# how to call multiple onkeyup events on one html-tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

can i call multiple onkeyup events on the same html input-tag?

```
<input style="float: left; width: 50px;" id="PersonLength" name="PersonLength" onkeyup="checkNr(this.id)" onkeyup="fill()" type="text">
```

something like that?

```
<input style="float: left; width: 50px;" id="PersonLength" name="PersonLength"  
onkeyup="checkNr(this.id), fill()" type="text">
```

or like this? ive treid them both but i might have the wrong syntax? or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You do not *call* `onkeyup` events, they are events, they *happen*.

You can use the EventListener API to add multiple event listeners.

```
var input = document.getElementById("my_input");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    doSomething();
});
input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    doSomethingElse();
});
// .. etc
```

The alternative notation would be:

```
<input .. onkeyup="checkNr(this.id); fill()" type="text">
                                   ^- semicolon
```

This is similar to:

```
var input = document.getElementById("my_input");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    checkNr(input.id);
    fill();
});
```

Comment: i need to have the eventlistener in the html tag like in my code

Comment: @DanielGustafsson See his second "alternative notation" - using a semi-colon between function calls is the key. You could also have both functions inside one general function and call that one function.

Comment: If you add an e parameter to the first two bound functions, then you can access the source element via the event object e. This allows access to the id of the target object, similar to the 2nd method of doing it, but without requiring the variable that's declared outside the function.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to Rome:

If you want to call multiple functions and set the event inline, you could write an extra method that will call all methods.

for ex.

```
<input style="float: left; width: 50px;" id="PersonLength" name="PersonLength" onkeyup="yourElemOnKeyup(this.id)" type="text">
```

Script

```
    function yourElemOnKeyup(id){
       checkNr(id);
       fill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy. Use whatever the method is you can use

```
onchange/onclick="method1() && method2();"
```

Comment: If `method1` were to return `false`, does method2 even get executed? Because the and operator gets optimized so that it doesn't need to execute `method2`. I would replace `&&` with another `;`

Comment: yeah but if you want to call two methods then you can choose this otherwise use this Event Listener best example  like this  input = document.getElementById("my_input");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    doSomething();
});
input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    doSomethingElse();
});wuerfelfreak

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="">
         <input type="number" name="admissionNumber" id="admissionNumber" onkeyup="getStudentName(); getStudentClassName()">
    </form>
    <script>
      function getStudentName(){
      }
      function getStudentClassName(){
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).